# How to rename multiple files like in Windows

Tags: batch-rename

I have a directory of songs all of which are from the same singer. I want to rename all the files in the directory as:

```
SingerName(1)
SingerName(2)
SingerName(3)
...
```

Just like we could do in Windows by selecting files and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or clicking on <kbd>rename</kbd> in the right-click menu for the selected files.

But this does not seem to work in Ubuntu 12.04! How can I rename a group of files?

Comment: specifically for this case you could use something like `n=0; for f in *; do printf -v new "SingerName(%01d$((++n)))"; echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"; done` (remove `echo` after testing)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install pyRenamer from software center 
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pyrenamer/

Answer (score 0):

It always been a good practice to do task using Terminal.
Link to your answer : [How to Bulk Rename Files in Linux (Terminal or GUI)](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal)

**OR** you can give a shot to any GUI app. You can find many.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, GPrename.

No rename app works better than it, at least for me. Its got GUI that's simple to use.